# Where to determine different behaviour for a child class with feature flags

Tags: solid, encapsulation, features

Let's say that I have a `Parent` class and a `Child` class, `Parent` relies on `Child` to perform, say, some network request:

```
class Parent {

  ...

  public init(){
    const child = new Child();
    const stuff = child.fetchStuff()
  }
}
```

```
class Child {

  public fetchStuff(){
    const stuff = fetch("blah blah");
    return stuff
  }
}
```

Now, using [feature flags](https://launchdarkly.com/blog/what-are-feature-flags/#:%7E:text=Feature%20flags%20are%20a%20software,portions%20of%20code%20are%20executed.), we want to develop a feature for which `Child` is going to fetch the stuff in a different way, we should also keep the old way of fetching stuff operative.

In order to do that, we are going to use the `featureFlags` service that for this example we supposed to be magically injected into the classes.

Now on to the question, where the check of the feature flag should exist? Should that be in the `Parent` or in the `Child` class?

#### Solution 1: In the parent class

```
class Parent {

  private featureFlags;

  public init(){
    const child = new Child();
    let stuff = null;
    if (this.featureFlags.isOn('feature')) stuff = child.fetchStuffB();
    else stuff = child.fetchStuffA();
  }

}
```

In this example, `Child` provides two methods to fetch the stuff in the new and the old way.

- Pros

  - No need for `Child` to be aware of feature flags, achieving loose coupling
  - `Child` in this way is easier to test
- Cons

  - In a way `Child` knows that there are 2 ways to do a thing, so why should not be aware of the feature flag at all?
  - In the lifecycle of a feature flag, this is removed, whenever we are going to remove it work is going to be required on both the `Parent` and the `Child` class

#### Solution 2: In the child class

Let's suppose that `Parent` is unchanged and is still calling just `fetchStuff`:

```
class Child {

  private featureFlags;

  public fetchStuff(){
    let stuff = null;
    if (this.featureFlags.isOn('feature')) stuff = this.fetchStuffB():
    else stuff = this.fetchStuffA();
    return stuff;
  }

}
```

- Pros

  - `Parent` just want the stuff, it does not care how it is done or how it is fetched
  - When this feature flag is going to be removed, work is required in this class only
- Cons

  - This class relies on the `featureFlags` service (I said previously that the `featureFlags` is magically injected anywhere but the truth is that I don't really like it)
  - Harder to test, in order to test the behaviour of `fetchStuff`, one need to be aware of the feature flag used internally, breaking in this way encapsulation

I see valid arguments on both sides, what should I go with? I'm more on the side of the first solution because I like that the `Child` class is transparent about how is doing something and why.

Also this is a question about maintainability, let's say that I have dozens if not hundreds of classes that need to do things differently according to feature flags, should the checks live only in well known places/classes or are we ok in putting this just before the lines of code that determines the change, no matter where they are?

Comment: One solution you appear not to have considered to to create a `Child2` class with the new behaviour, and your DI framework then registers the right class.

Comment: What if `Child` is a reasonable big class and only one line of code needs to be done differently? Should I extract that line in another class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you check the feature flag depends on the scope of the feature.

Checking the feature flag in the Parent class is ideal for cases where you do not want the Child class behavior changed globally. If you only want the new behavior as part of the Parent class, check the feature flag in Parent before deciding which method on Child to call.

If you find that every invocation of `Child.fetchStuff()` is preceded by checking the feature flag, then solution #2 becomes ideal. The Child class should check the feature flag and execute behavior accordingly. This keeps knowledge of the feature flag limited and easier to clean up.

Another option to consider is creating a sub class of Child, which overrides `fetchStuff()` with the new behavior.

```
class Child {
    fetchStuff() {
        // old behavior
    }
}

class NewFeatureChild extends Child {
    override fetchStuff() {
        // new behavior
    }
}
```

The Parent class would still expect a Child object, which could be of type `Child` or `NewFeatureChild`. The code example you provided shows Parent initializing a Child object. Depending on what these classes are responsible for, you might want to initialize Child or NewFeatureChild elsewhere, and pass this in as a constructor parameter for Parent.

```
Child child;

if (featureFlags.isOn('featureA')) {
    child = new Child();
}
else {
    child = new NewFeatureChild();
}

parent = new Parent(child);
```

This pushes the check for the feature up the call stack. This might be ideal for situations where Parent is some sort of service class or data access class, which gets configured in a dependency injection container in the composition root of the application. This is not so ideal for domain or business classes, though, which are typically initialized closer to a use case, and further away from the composition root.

Comment: I think your final option is likely the best long term option.  Even if it is a domain class, it would be advantagous (for unit testing if nothing else) to invert its dependency on the class used for `fetching` data.

Comment: Definitely a good plan to suggest inverting the dependency here, supports DI frameworks as well.

Comment: "*Another option to consider is creating a sub class of Child*" - I see no reason for inheritance here. For better decoupling, rather make a `Child` interface and implement separate `ChildA` and `ChildB` classes.

Comment: @Bergi, and then what? Copy and paste the entire class? To be honest, inheritance is not my favorite solution here. If used, I would advocate for this being temporary. Once you believe the feature is stable, move the logic to the class it should be in, and delete the derived class.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Why copy anything? The class only has one method, `fetchStuff`, making this a classical [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Depending on the language (the code might be TypeScript, Java, C#? But probably is meant to be pseudo code), you wouldn't even use a class but just pass a function. If there's multiple methods in the strategies, I'd argue that each strategy would have its own implementation for each method (not sharing code) or the SRP and ISP would be violated.

Comment: I don't think we can make that assumption based on the information in the question, but I think I see what you are going for. That could be a viable solution too, but we would need way more information to make that judgement.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer with such an abstract example, there are situations where both options are the most ideal. Ultimately, the question is which class "knowing" about the flag makes the most sense. Keeping in mind that the best answer may be—very likely probably is—neither.

Since you mention fetch, let's consider caching as an example:

It might make more sense in the parent if the flag is `preferCache` is a situation is like: If the flag is set, call `child.fetchA()`, but if it isn't set, fails, or if the user clicked refresh, call `child.fetchB()`. Basically any situation where parent needs to know about both methods at run time.

It might make more sense in the child if the flag is `cacheEnabled` and the situation is: "Is the cache enabled, if so attempt to fetch cached data?" Especially if the cache behavior is constant and neither requires nor accepts input from the parent.

But ultimately, it probably makes sense in neither as caching could be built directly into the mechanism child uses to fetch the data.

In the second or third case, a factory is probably your best bet. Greg's answer (very correctly) points out how to set up multiple versions of child and select which version to pass into parent, but expanding that one step and implementing the factory pattern would move the decision logic out from the instantiation of parent into a separate class and you'd pass the factory into parent instead of the child. (And it's possible that the child should call a factory that provides the necessary change, considering you pointed out that the change is very small and may be out of scope of the parent.) This also avoids repetition if parent is not the only consumer of child and protects you if the flag can be changed at runtime.

This aligns with Philip's comment as well, as most DI frameworks use the factory pattern (implicitly or explicitly) to determine the correct versions of various classes and provide them based on system context.